# Declare Struct for DLL in OpenOffice Basic

Tags: vba, translate, libreoffice-basic

I've got some (32 bit) Office VBA I'd like to port to Libre Office or similar:

```
Type wsaData
    wVersion As Integer
    wHighVersion As Integer
    szDescription As String * WSA_DescriptionSize
    szSystemStatus As String * WSA_SysStatusSize
    iMaxSockets As Integer
    iMaxUdpDg As Integer
    lpVendorInfo As String * 200
End Type

Public Declare Function WSAStartup Lib "ws2_32.dll" (wVersionRequested As Integer, lpWSAData As wsaData) As Long
```

However, the packing and type declarations for Libre Office Basic are different than MS Office VBA, and the Libre/Open office version crashes irretrievably. (Unlike MS Office for Windows, LO doesn't provide stack protection to DLL/dylib calls)

So far I haven't found *any* documentation for 'Declare Function', (which must be somewhere), but I also specifically need guidelines for passing strings and structs to declared dlls (which FAIK may not even be possible)

If anyone's done that specific struct before I'll be pleased :), but I also need guidelines.

Comment: Two thoughts. In VBA the first would be declared as ByVal - `wVersionRequested ByVal As Integer`.The second parameter would be passed `ByRef` I don't know Libre, `ByRef` is the default but I would specify it anyway in case the compiler cares. In the docs I see nothing about Unicode versus ANSI. I don't know Libre but make sure you are passing null terminated ANSI or UNICODE strings. In VBA to pass a Unicode string you assign text to a byte array. `Dim A()` then `A="MyString` To pass the string you pass the first element - `A(0)`.

Comment: Are you limited to Basic? I normally use the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) library in LibreOffice python-UNO macros. Either write it all in python, or write it mostly in Basic and then call a python function from Basic that uses the ctypes library. Note: If the only reason you're thinking of using LO Basic is to save time because it's similar to MS VBA, that's probably not a good reason — no matter whether you decide on Basic or python, you'll need to rewrite most of the VBA code.

Comment: As far as I am aware, LibreOffice/OpenOffice BASIC doesn't support the asterisk notation for setting the maximum length of a string variable, so I would first try removing those. A good reference for the syntax of calling functions from DLLs can be found in Section 9.2.3 on Page 205 of "OpenOffice.org Macros Explained" by Andrew Pitonyak, which can be downloaded from http://www.pitonyak.org/OOME_3_0.pdf . This is also the best first port of call for LibreOffice/OpenOffice BASIC generally.

Comment: @Jim-K That was true 20 years ago, when OO did not implement the excel object model, but is no longer the case.  I've got LO python, so that is possible, but the reason is to avoid having separate excel and LO versions of code. At the moment, structure declarations is the only blocking point.

Comment: "The reason is to avoid having separate excel and LO versions of code" — Okay, that is different. People who ask questions here often have a convoluted Excel macro and then hope it will work in LO Basic, but it doesn't due to the very many API differences. But if you're careful, it's possible to write code that works for both.